# How to implement Theme Switcher From a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am making a small react project and I was happy with my progress and decide to create a dark theme. I've found a way to make it work inside the app tsx file in which I have linked. But I want to put that button in my navbar component. The problem is my main app tsx div takes in the `data-theme={theme}` code. My question is how will I pass in the 'theme' from an external component? I've linked images to my `app.tsx`, `navbar.tsx`, `app.css`, and project structure.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can pass your `switchTheme` function as a prop to `Navbar`, and then call `switchTheme` from inside the `Navbar` component.

For example, inside your App component you'd do this:

`<Navbar switchTheme={switchTheme} />`

And in your Navbar component:

```
function Navbar({switchTheme}){
   return(
      <button onClick={switchTheme}>Switch Theme</button>
   )
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the response. Second, sorry if I'm misinterpreting, but are you saying I can switch the theme from the Navbar component?

Comment: No problem. Yes, you can switch the theme from the Navbar component. I edited my answer to have an example.